# Scroll Event Not working on mobile with sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi so im trying to change my navbar to sticky and apply it when the page is being scrolled.  It works perfectly on desktop version with this code but it doesnt apply to the mobile version.

```
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function()
    {
    var nav=document.querySelector("nav")
    nav.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0)
    
    })
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to  I

Answer (score 1):

if parent element is nav it will work without js

```
// CSS
nav {
position: sticky
}
```

if it's header

```
// CSS
header {
position: sticky
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use an event listener. Have a look at position: sticky attribute [here](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)